# Use of variables in Linq for property

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to return results from a List based on various search parameters and operators.
But I would like to avoid a long if then else list for all the combinations, so it would be nice to be able to use variables in the Linq search... Something like this (which obviously is not working):

```
//NOW searchParameter contains one of the following: "orderNumber", "customerOrderNumber", "customerCode", "customerName", "shippingCity", "shippingCountry"
//AND searchOperator contains one of the following: "equalto", "notequalto", "before", "after", "lessthan", "morethan"
//AND searchCriteria is either a string or a DateTime
if (searchOperator == "equalto")    
{
    List<SalesOrder> results = Program.salesOrderCollection.getSalesOrders().Where(o => o[searchParameter].Equals(searchCriteria)).ToList();
}
```

Can you give me some ideas for achieving this? Thanks.

Comment: What is wrong with the `if/else` pattern you are using now?

Comment: have a look at Expression trees, it might give you an inspiration of a solution you might need

Comment: @DavidG I Think that I would need a lot of very similar lines just to query on every parameter. I'm looking for something like in SQL where you can build the query string out of variables.

Comment: instead of write lots of if then code you could pass function parameter like this Func<SalesOrder, bool> criteria = o => o[searchParameter].Equals(searchCriteria);
            var results = order.OrderItems.Where(criteria).ToList();

Comment: The thing is that this syntax o[searchParameter] is not supported in place of e.g. o.orderNumber as far as I can see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you want to use a string as search parameter? Strings are for humans, not for computers!

### Separate your concerns

This means: separate your input from the processing and from the output.

The only reason to use a string would be if you have some external source of which you don't know the origin, like a human (okay, sometimes an external computer). If you have a UI, where an operator types a string that represents the parameter he wants to use, you should immediately convert to what his input stands for: this input is not meant to be used as a string, but as parameter predicate in a `Where` statement.

In your case, this parameter has the format of `Func<SalesOrder, bool>`, or if it is a database query: `Expression<Func<SalesOrder, bool>>`

The advantage of such a conversion function is that you can check validity of the input string in an early stage, immediately after the operator finished entering his data. Another example of course is re-usability: if the predicate parameter came from another source than a human entering a string, for instance, a human selecting an item in a combo box, or another part of your program, you can re-use your processing part.

Apart from re-usabilitiy, other advantages of separating your concerns would be that the code is easier to understand, easier to change and easier to test. Changes in requirements would lead to smaller changes in your code.

For example: your requirement is now that the operator selects the parameter to use in the search string from a combo box, containing items like `Id`, `OrderDate`, `CustomerName`.

But suppose you have a new requirements

- Change your forms application that operators can select CustomerName Kennedy or OrderDate > January 2019
- Make a command line version of the program where users can type `-CustomerName Kennedy`, but also `CUSTOMERNAME kennedy`, `-c Kennedy`, and even `-cuSTOMErname KENnedY`

If you have one procedure that converts the input into a `Func<SalesOrder, bool>`, your processing and output don't have to change.

So let's separate!

### Back to your question

**Input**: two strings: a `paramName`and a `paramValue`, `paramName` is the name of the Parameter to use, and `paramValue` is a string representation of the value to compare with.

It should be possible to convert `paramValue` from string to the proper type of the parameter. So if the parameter is a `DateTime`, then `paramValue` should be a string that can be converted to a `DateTime`.

**Output:** The `Func<SalesOrder, bool>` representing parameter Predicate that can be used in a Where statement to select a subset of SalesOrders.

```
class InputConverter
{
  static Func<SalesOrder, bool> ToWherePredicate(string paramName, string paramValue)
  {
    switch (paramName)
    {
      case "Id:"
        int value = Int32.Parse(paramValue);
        return salesOrder => salesOrder.Id == value;
        break;
      case "OrderDate":
        DateTime value = DateTime.Parse(paramValue);
        return salesOrder => salesOrder.OrderDate == value;
        break;
      case "CustomerId":
        int value = Int32.Parse(paramValue);
        return salesOrder => salesOrder.CustomerId == value;
        break;
      case ...

      default:
        // Other string values are not supported
        throw new NotSupportedException(...);
    }
  }
}
```

See how easy it will be to extend this function to accept inputs like `-Date`, `-Id`, for a command line?

The extension function you where waiting for: a `Where` that takes as input a sequence of `SalesOrders` and a `KeyValuePair<string, string>` and has as output the selected `SalesOrders` will now be a one-liner.

I decided to create it as an extension function. This way you can use it as if it was a standard LINQ function See [Extension Methods Demystified](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2013/03/08/c.net-little-wonders-extension-methods-demystified.aspx)

```
static IEnumerable<SalesOrder> Where(this IEnumerable<SalesOrder> salesOrders,
       string paramName, string paramValue)
{
  Func<SalesOrder, bool> predicate = InputConverter.ToWherePredicate(paramName, paramValue)
  return salesOrders.Where(predicate);
}
```

Usage, reading input from a ComboBox and a TextBox (in baby steps):

```
string paramName = (string)comboBoxParamName.SelectedValue;
string paramValue = (string)textBoxParamValue.SelectedValue

var requestedSalesOrders = Program.salesOrderCollection.getSalesOrders()
    .Where(paramName, paramValue)
    .GroupBy(salesOrder => salesOrder.OrderDate)
    .OrderBy(group => group.Key)
    ...
```

See that because I created it as an extension function of IEnumerable, it behaves exactly like any other LINQ function.

One final remark: if function `GetSalesOrders` returns an `IQueryable<SalesOrder>` instead of an `IEnumerable<SalesOrder>`, you should use `Expression<Func<SalesOrder, bool>>` instead of `Func<SalesOrder, bool>`. The lambda expressions in `ToPredicate` will not change.

Comment: Thanks for your very detailed and good answer. I guess there's no way of escaping the writing of every combination. Your solution doesn't seem to cater for the operator though such as orderDate > some date or tax < some value. I guess I need to work that into the switch statement as well by adding another parameter to the Func?

Comment: If you want to convert a string to a piece of code, then essentially it is writing a small compiler. It is possible to split a string with parameter, operator and value into three parts, and then write a converter